# (Unary Union) in ZF

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have just started reading up on the Zermelo-Fraenkel (ZF) axioms, and am confused with the **axiom of union**. Here is the definition that I am working with -

For each set $A$, there is a set which consists of exactly the elements of elements of $A$. More formally, $\forall A \ \exists \ B \ \forall \ c \ (c \in B \iff \exists \ D \ (c \in D \land D \in A))$.

For example, let $A=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$. Then, $\bigcup A =\{1,2\} =B$. This satisfies the union axiom since we have $1 \in B$, and $\{1\} \in A$ such that $1 \in \{1\}$. The same applies for the other element of $B$, which is $2$.

However, how does one make sense of the (unary) union of the set $B=\{1,2\}$? The elements of $B$ themselves are not sets, so the only logical interpretation I can think of is $\bigcup B = \emptyset$. Any clarification on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: All objects are sets when you work in ZF. So the answer depends on how you interpret the symbols $1$ and $2$ as sets. There are many good options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of $B$ are indeed sets because everything in ZF is a set, in particular, natural numbers are defined to be certain sets. Usually, you define $1 = \{ 0\}, 2 = \{1,0\},$ etc. Using that definition, you get $\bigcup B = \bigcup \{\{0\},\{0,1\}\} = \{0,1\} = 2$.

Comment: Interesting. So I assume this works by defining $1=\{0\}, 2=1 \ \bigcup \ \{1\}=\{0,1\},$ and in general (inductively), $n+1= n \ \bigcup \ \{n\}$?

Comment: yes, exactly! also, 0 is (fairly naturally) defined to be the empty set

Comment: Right, cool, thanks for the clarification. One more question - how about something like $0.5$? Can I say $0.5 = 0 \ \bigcup \ \{0.5\} = \{{0.5}\}$?

Comment: no, integer, rational and real numbers use more complex constructions. I don't know any references off the top of my head, but even the Wikipedia articles on the respective types of numbers have a solid overview on how they can be constructed

Comment: Great, thank you!